# A question on surjectivity of a bilinear quadratic map

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, linear-algebra, polynomials, multilinear-algebra

Let $a=(a_0, a_1, ..., a_n )$, $b=(b_0, b_1, ..., b_n )$ that belong to ${\mathbb R}^{n+1}$. Define polynomials $f_a (t)=a_0 +a_1 t+ ... + a_n t^n$ and $f_b (t)=b_0 +b_1 t+ ... + b_n t^n$ and let $f_{ab}(t)=f_a (t)f_b '(t)-f_a '(t)f_b (t)=c_0 +c_1 t+ ... + c_{2n-2} t^{2n-2}$, where $'$ denotes derivative. From the above setting we may define the (bilinear) map $F$ : ${\mathbb R}^{2n+2} \to {\mathbb R}^{2n-1}$, $F(a,b)=c$.

QUESTION: Is $F$ onto?

If so, is it known what the fiber $F^{-1}(c)$ will look like?

Comment: Please write the formulas in LaTeX.

Comment: Reformulated question: let $\mathbb{R}_k[t]$ denote the space of real polynomials of degree $\le k$. Let $F:\mathbb{R}_n[t]\times\mathbb{R}_n[t]\to \mathbb{R}_{2n-2}[t]$ be the skew-symmetric bilinear map $(A,B)\mapsto AB'-A'B$ (note the collapsing of the two main coefficients, which makes this valued here rather than in $\mathbb{R}_{2n-1}[t]$). Is $F$ surjective?

Comment: The differential at $(1,t^n)$ is surjective, if I'm correct. So, the image has non-empty interior (and, at the complex level, the image contains a Zariski dense open subset).

Comment: Yes, but the problem is **real** surjectivity, for which just a single differential is not sufficient.

Comment: I know, that's why I didn't claim it as an answer. And even in the complex case a single surjective differential is not enough.

Comment: @YCor: That would be enough, as we can make the problem projective, but, as we see, over reals that doesn't hold :)

Comment: How do you make the problem projective? one problem is that $F$ maps some pairs of nonzero elements to 0.

Answer (score 2):

No, $F$ is not onto in general.  For example, it is not difficult to show that, when $n=3$, the polynomial
$$
c = c_0 + c_1t + c_2 t + c_3 t^3 + c_4 t^4
$$
is in the image of $F$ if and only if 
$$
12\,c_0c_4 - 3\,c_1c_3 + {c_2}^2 \ge 0.
$$

To see this, note that if $c = F(a,b)$ as above, then
$$
12\,c_0c_4 - 3\,c_1c_3 + {c_2}^2 = (3a_0b_3-3a_3b_0-a_1b_2+a_2b_1)^2\ge0.
$$
To prove the converse direction, note that, if the above inequality holds,
then, taking the square root of the above equation, one finds that one can solve for all of the expressions $a_ib_j-a_jb_i$ for $0\le i < j \le 3$, and this determines $a$ and $b$ uniquely up to a unimodular linear combination.

Comment: If $c=c_0+\dots+c_4t^4$ is as above with $12c_0c_4-3c_1c_3+c_2^2<0$ (for instance, $c=t^4-1$) do you know if it still holds that $c$ does not belong to the image for any $n\ge 3$?

Comment: @YCor:  No, that doesn't happen.  For example, if $f_a(t) = 1 + \tfrac13t^4$ and $f_b(t) = -t$, then one has $$f_{ab}(t) = t^4-1.$$

Comment: @YCor:  Further, taking $f_a(t) = 1$, one can solve $f'_b(t) = c(t)$ for any given polynomial $c(t)$ to get a polynomial $f_b(t)$, so not bounding the degrees makes the problem trivial.